# Which pronunciation of 云 (yun) is correct?

Tags: mandarin, pronunciation

Google Translate has a different pronunciation of 云 (yun) than this website: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/pronunciation/Yun

The Google Translate one sounds like more the Cantonese pronunciation of "far" whereas the other one is more like "yween".

Google Translate: https://translate.google.com/#en/zh-CN/cloud

Which is correct?

Comment: The pinyin **yun** is short form of **yuen**, so the right pronunciation is yee-woo-en.

Comment: Unless you reside in Hong Kong, which Google translate might switch the pronunciation to Cantonese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go to [汉典](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/4E91.htm) to listen the sound files.

Both 拼音 and 注音 pronounce the same sound.

This is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/7688/

> 云
>
> wan4   (jyutping)
>
> yun2   (pinyin)
>
> [1] [archaic] say; speak
>
> [2] simplified form of 雲

Both 雲 and 云 are pronounced as /yun2/ (with raising end tone)